# AnsiStrIComp fails comparing strings in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, unicode, string, delphi-2010

I'm slightly confused and hoping for enlightenment.

I'm using Delphi 2010 for this project and I'm trying to compare 2 strings.

Using the code below fails

```
if AnsiStrIComp(PAnsiChar(sCatName), PAnsiChar(CatNode.CatName)) = 0 then...
```

because according to the debugger only the first character of each string is being compared (i.e. if `sCatName` is `"Automobiles"`, `PAnsiChar(sCatName)` is `"A"`).

I want to be able to compare strings that may be in different languages, for example English vs Japanese.

In this case I am looking for a match, but I have other functions used for sorting, etc. where I need to know how the strings compare (less than, equal, greater than).

Comment: sCatName is defined as string, which to my understanding in Delphi 2010 is = UnicodeString.
In this particular case it is being passed a function parameter--
function ExtractCatagory2Listbox(sCatName: String; TargetLB: TListBox): Boolean;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that `sCatName` and `CatNode.CatName` are defined as `string`s (= `UnicodeString`s)?. They should be.

There is no need to convert the strings to null-terminated strings! This you (mostly) only need to do when working with the Windows API.

If you want to test equality of two strings, use `SameStr(S1, S2)` (case sensitive matching) or `SameText(S1, S2)` (case insensitive matching), or simply `S1 = S2` in the first case. All three options return `true` or `false`, depending on the strings equality.

If you want to get a numerical value based on the ordinal values of the characters (as in sorting), then use `CompareStr(S1, S2)` or `CompareText(S1, S2)`. These return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer.

(You might want to use the `Ansi-` functions: `AnsiSameStr`, `AnsiSameText`, `AnsiCompareStr`, and `AnsiCompareText`; these functions will use the current locale. The non `Ansi-` functions will accept a third, optional parameter, explicitly specifying the locale to use.)

## Update

Please read Remy Lebeau's comments regarding the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
For the function in question AnsiCompareText() looks like it will do the job as well as being a simpler implementation.
But I would like to understand why PAnsiChar(sCatName) is taking a string variable and returning only the first character.

Comment: If `sCatName` is a string, then `PAnsiChar(sCatName)` creates a null-terminated string representation of `sCatName`, and returns the pointer, the address, of the first character of this null-terminated string. (In Delphi, `string`s are *not* null-terminated, so when communicating with the Windows API, for instance, you might need to create null-terminated strings from Delphi strings).

Comment: The UnicodeString type uses UTF-16 encoding, which uses 2 bytes per codeunit, and 1-2 codeunits per Unicode character (depending on whether surrogates are used). For Unicode characters in the ASCII range, the second byte of each codeunit will be set to 0. Type-casting a UnicodeString to a PAnsiChar will treat the pointer as a null-terminated Ansi character string, not a null-terminated Unicode character string. So the pointer will always end at the second byte of the string.

Comment: @Andreas: Delphi strings ARE null-terminated.  The null terminator is not considered part of the string data (it is not counted by Length(string)), but the terminator is present nontheless.  This is so a PChar typecast can simply return the address of the string data as-is without having to allocate new memory instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I wasn't aware of that null byte. But indeed it makes sense - it is a very small cost for a potentially huge improvement of performance!

Comment: @Remy: You really should have downvoted me, at least until I removed the incorrect statement about the non-existing null byte!

Comment: Here we can observe the null character: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types

Comment: Keep in mind that relying on nullchar termination will go wrong for certain strings (e.g. compare aaaa#0bbb with aaaa#0ccc), since it is perfectly legal for Delphi strings to contain additional null chars

Answer (score 0):

What about simple `sCatName=CatNode.CatName`? If they are `strings` it should work.

Comment: I am looking for non-case sensitive comparison. In this particular case I am checking for equality. While UpperCase(sCatName)=UpperCase(CatNode.Name) would work (for this particular example) it is my understanding the the built-in string comparison functions are faster.

Comment: @TheSteven: Yes, `SameText(A, B)` is faster than `AnsiUpperCase(A) = AnsiUpperCase(B)`.

Comment: @TheSteven I was cut off from the internet, and so I missed the whole discussion; now I must just agree with Andreas and Remy.